# How to search file with a specific extension and perform searching operation on that file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Would appreciate if anyone could share how to search file with specific extension and perform operation on that file,

I have a base folder which contains many folders with different extensions, and I would like to search for a `.sql` extension file containing the strings, `commit`, `exit` and `/`. If they do not exist, then add those strings to that file.

So far I have created a batch script which returns all SQL file names within the directory tree to a file named `directoryList.txt`.

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
set "writePath=E:\Base_Package_oracle\oracle_rep"
type nul>directoryList.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /B /A:D /S "E:\Base_Package_oracle\*.*"') do (
    if exist "%%~ff\*.sql" (
        rem findstr "commit"
        rem echo commit exist
        echo "%%~ff">> directoryList.txt
    ) else (
        echo file not found
    )
)
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('type directoryList.txt') do (
    echo xcopy "%%~f" "%writePath%" /e/v/c/y/h/r/d
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with Bash?

Comment: I think you many need to be more specific with your search criteria. Are you positive you want every file which does not contain all three of those search terms anywhere within them? Or perhaps you really wanted those which do not end with exactly those three terms, in that order, one per line. Also I cannot believe that every `.sql` file within an entire directory tree, should have those three commands/lines in them anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -i -r -v -e 'commit|exit|/' --include \*.sql (filepath) | xargs echo "commit exit /" >>
```

`-i` ignore uppercase
`-r` search recursively
`-v` find files which do not contain the words "commit", "exit", "/"
`-e` search for the pattern

`|` pipe to the xargs command
`echo "commit exit /" >>` to append these words to the file

the words appended may need to be changed to your requirements

This answer is for bash

Comment: The [[tag:bash]] tag was removed, _(sixteen minutes before you posted this answer)_, because the question code is not a shell script, _(which can be invoked via a Bourne Again SHell)_. It is clearly a Windows [[tag:batch-file]], and that therefore is the only relevant programming language to fix that incomplete task code.

Comment: I was researching on answering the question. After answering the question, I read this was a question regarding the batch language and not bash.

Comment: My above comment was for courtesy, as viewers may note that your answer does not match the question code language, you may receive downvotes for it. Given that it cannot solve the coding issue submitted, I know what I'd do, but the choice is yours whether you wish for it to remain.